unable to render partial view into hidden field
In our previous .NET 4.8 project, we were able to render the output of partial views as text, like this:
@Html.Hidden("hdnContent", Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_content.cshtml", Model).ToHtmlString())

This worked fine - the HTML output of the partial was captured as a string in the hidden field.
However, when I try and do the same thing in ASP.NET Core 9.0 MVC, the following is rendered in the hidden field:

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Buffers.ViewBuffer

I have tried a couple of different approaches when rendering the partial, such as below:
@{
      var content = (await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Shared/_content.cshtml", Model)).ToString();
}

@Html.Hidden("hdnContent", content)

But I consistently see the same result.
Is there a way to achieve what I had previously in .NET 4.8?

I managed to solve this by writing a custom view renderer.
The following question/answer helped me to solve this: Return View as String in .NET Core
in particular, Pharylon's answer.
